# Jquery validation check inside the table without submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am stuck with jquery validation.

HTML CODE:

```html
<form id="userworklog">
  <tr>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Charge#Field</th>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="date" name="date">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="date" name="enddate">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="projectkey" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="chargefield" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="userlist" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

using sQuery ajax call I get the list of userlist, project and charge.

After the user name is selected

```
$("#userList").change(function() {
  //need to validate the startdate and end date field  and pass the all values to 
  // getaddlist(projkey,userkey,startdate,enddate);             
});
```

I could achieve all the functionlity.but validation check was not validating and displaying error.

I tried

```js
$("#userList").change(function() {
  var userkey = $(userList).val();
  var projkey = $("#projectsList").val();
  var chargelist = $("#chargelist").val();
  var startdate = $("#startdate").val();
  var enddate = $("#enddate").val();
  if (startdate == " " && enddate == " ") {
    initFormValidation();
  } else {
    getIssueList(projkey, userkey, startdate, enddate);
  }
});
}

function initFormValidation() {
  $("#userworklog").validate({
    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
      startdate: "required",
      enddate: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      startdate: " Please enter Startdate",
      enddate: " Please enter End date"
    },

  });
}
```

if start date is present or not. it's going to get issuelist

Comment: Please note the missing > on the selects I added and also that there is a } too many which is visible now I indented to code correctly for you

Comment: still validation is not checking....

Comment: I did not fix your code, just explained one error

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).  Use the `.valid()` method to programmatically trigger validation from within your `.change()` handler function.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery validation have following syntax:

```
$('form_id').validate({
    rules:{

    },
    messages:{

    }
});
```

It will automatically initiated when a input submit is clicked in the associated form. But in case of input type button we can initaite the validation like:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    if($('form_id').valid())    // it will initiate the validation
    {
        // do your stuff here, it will work only when data is valid
    }
});
```

Comment: No submit button in the form...can be please make brief

Comment: In that case you can use $('#button').click(function(){}); or any event of any html element in the same manner.

Comment: Add the same as you suggested..but not working